# multiple instance of discord.py bots with multiprocessing issue with instances that doesn't listenning to events

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing

I'm making a `discord.py` snippets that should have multiple `discord.py` bots instance.

A bot is represented as follows

```py
class Bot(commands.Bot):

    client = discord.Client()

    def __init__(self, token):
        intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, members=True, guilds=True)
        self.client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
        self.token = token

        print("Bot is starting...")

    @client.event
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f"{self.user} has connected to Discord!")

    async def run(self):
        print("Bot is running...")
        try:
            await self.run()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

But in console, I'm only getting `Bot is starting...` 3 times because I have 3 tokens

The main bootstrapper code is like that

```py
def launch_bot(bot_instance: Bot):
    asyncio.run(bot_instance.run())


async def main():
    global global_bots_queue
    global global_bots

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

    guild_name = input('Enter the desired guild name: ')
    global_bots_queue = retrieve_tokens()

    for token in global_bots_queue:
        global_bots[token] = Bot(token)

    for token in global_bots_queue:
        pool.apply_async(launch_bot, args=(global_bots[token],))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    event_loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

What should I edit to make this code works, please?

Output :

```
Bot is starting...
Bot is starting...
Bot is starting...
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The multiprocessing system you were using was fucked up, so I changed it a bit and tested it works now

```
class Bot(commands.Bot):

    def __init__(self, token):
        intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, members=True, guilds=True)
        super().__init__(command_prefix="!", description="A bot for the Discord server", intents=intents)
        self.token = token
        print("Bot is starting...")

    
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f"Bot has connected to Discord!")


    def run_(self):
        print("Bot is running...")
        try:
            self.run(self.token)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)


def main():
    global global_bots_queue
    global global_bots

    global_bots_queue = retrieve_tokens()

    # for token in global_bots_queue:
    #     global_bots[token] = Bot(token)

    proccess = []
    global_bots = []
    for token in global_bots_queue:
        proccess.append(Process(target=Bot(token).run_, args=()))
        global_bots.append(Bot(token))

    for p in proccess:
        p.start()

    for p in proccess:
        p.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It can't find self and that's normal

Comment: @AlexisC.Gridel I changed take a look at it, it will run now

Comment: on_ready doesn't trigger

Comment: @AlexisC.Gridel the problem is with multiprocessing system

Comment: I don't really see where's wrong

Comment: @AlexisC.Gridel the multiprocessing system you were using wasn't even calling the function `launch_bot` also i edited my answer you can check if it works or not

Comment: https://pastebin.com/kzGb19MU

Comment: @AlexisC.Gridel try running it without event loop, just add the tokens in the token_list and it should run fine in the code that I have posted

Comment: https://pastebin.com/1ZECbY0m

Comment: @AlexisC.Gridel what is your current code now?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xQVzpQsw

Comment: @AlexisC.Gridel I ran it my pc it runs fine check my answer now

Comment: Same issue, here is my Bot.py code 

https://pastebin.com/91tJnu85

Comment: @AlexisC.Gridel see my Bot class our bot class are different you are not running the code i am giving

Comment: Even with the exact same code as yours I have the same issue

Comment: FYI: I have created a new project with the code you sent, and same issue

Comment: @AlexisC.Gridel https://imgur.com/a/Leo4Msa the bot runs with correct tokens here

Comment: https://gifyu.com/image/SbmKf

Comment: @AlexisC.Gridel you need separate for-loops to start processes and join them thats why you are getting the error look at how i have joined and started them

Comment: Same issue even if I'm separating them

Comment: @AlexisC.Gridel can you post the video of that

Comment: https://gifyu.com/image/SbmNS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241093/discussion-between-good-and-alexis-c-gridel).